# Adminlte in Laravel sidebar update label on runtime

Tags: php, laravel, sidebar, adminlte

This is my menu array format in adminlte.php

```
'menu' => [
        [
            'text' => 'Dashboard',
            'url'  => '/dashboard',
            'icon' => 'dashboard',
            'label'=> $test // how to pass variable here or alternative way without using building menu
            'label-color' => 'success'
        ],
],
```

How can I pass count variable to the label on runtime?

I knew there is a way to do it with building menu but, need to rebuild the whole thing inside adminlte.php . I need to pass count variable to it, if I put in adminlte.php, the variable will be undefined.

Can the building menu used to update the menu label or append the label and label-color into it?

Is there a method to override the current value in label by passing variable to it?

Comment: use the view composers, so the count variable will be available on runtime.

Comment: @abrar i tried, it will show Undefined variable: test in adminlte.php

Comment: Show your code here, How did you use in service provider.

Comment: @abrar view()->composer("*","App\Http\ViewComposers\testViewComposer");

Comment: What is the name of view where you want to show the counter ?

Comment: @abrar in adminlte.php i put $test, and viewComposer i return with test also.

Comment: don't you use the blade template? like adminlte.blade.php. give me full path of your adminlte.php view. so I can give you the correct code and solution.

Comment: @abrar resources/views/vendor/adminlte/page.blade.php will extends('adminlte::master') and in the resources/views/pages the blade will extends('adminlte::page').

Comment: I need the exact view name where you want to show the counter. is it page.blade.php ?

Comment: @abrar the counter variable is in config/adminlte.php . The sidebar will be called in every page. The problem is i cannot pass my variable to the adminlte.php. I am looking for a way without rebuild all my adminlte content using building menu.

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel-AdminLTE documentation:

It is also possible to configure the menu at runtime, e.g. in the boot of any service provider. Use this if your menu is not static, for example when it depends on your database or the locale. It is also possible to combine both approaches. The menus will simply be concatenated and the order of service providers determines the order in the menu.

To configure the menu at runtime, register a handler or callback for the MenuBuilding event, for example in the boot() method of a service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Events\BuildingMenu;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $events->listen(BuildingMenu::class, function (BuildingMenu $event) {
            $event->menu->add('MAIN NAVIGATION');
            $event->menu->add([
                'text' => 'Blog',
                'url' => 'admin/blog',
            ]);
        });
    }

}
```

https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#menu-configuration-at-runtime